# How can I get my cursor out of the textbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have a pretty complex visual studio form where I have like 2 textboxes, and some other stuff I need for my project, but my problem is - I want to use arrow keys to do tasks (bind them like short-cuts) and I can do that only when I don't edit my textboxes or else I get stuck in them and even if I try to reset my cursor (click on the form) it stays in the textbox and I can only jump in between characters, not use my arrows like I binded them. So my two questions are -

How can I reset my cursor if I have previously selected a textbox?

How can I unbind my default arrow keys so they don't jump between characters and buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a key event on the textboxes that catches the arrow key strokes and moves focus accordingly.

```
void inputField_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down))
        {
            //nextControl.Focus();
        }
    }
```

Just be aware that this will then remove the ability to navigate between the characters in a textbox. I think that the numpad arrows might still work inside the textbox since they have a different keycodes, but I can't be sure right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and Welcome to stackoverflow, I'm not sure i have a complete answere but I have a few thougth on the subject.

- Hard to answeer without some code, to se how you turns off the curser i think?
- why does it have to in the first place? seems to overcomlicate it abit ?

the way i whould go about this, it's to egnore the the muse curser all together at first, and make a on KeyDown event on the textbox that needs the to be able to shift to the next like this

```
    private void yourControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down || e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
        {
            // shift to next textbox maybe, to keep thing simple ? 
        }
    }
```

though this will act wierd if you use a mulitlines textbox or other control that allready have these keys bind.

you can allso add a field boolean as a switch to enable the keys, that gets set on the textsboxes activation (thats what happens then you click it to write text) and it can be reused, then it look like this

```
class yourProgram
{
    private bool fieldIskeysMode = false;
    private void yourControl_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (fieldIskeysMode) // if True
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down || e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            {
                // shift to next textbox maybe, to keep thing simple ? 
            }
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Escape) fieldIskeysMode = false; // one line set to falls on esc key 
        }
    }
    private void yourControl_Activate(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!fieldIskeysMode) // if not true 
        {
             fieldIskeysMode = true;
        }
    }
}
```

hope this helps.